# How to improve the accuracy of integration with Bessel function without significant drop in performance?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

Consider the following function and integral:

```
f[s_, T_, mN_] = T/(8*Pi^4)1/(mN^3 (s - 1.` mN^2)) (1 - mN^2/s)^2 Sqrt[s - 6.6564000000000005`]((-0.5` s - 1.6641000000000001`) mN^4 + (6.863591314910416` - 0.5` s) s mN^2 + s^2 (1.` s - 5.199491314910417`)) BesselK[1, Sqrt[s]/T] ;
int[mN_, T_] := 
 NIntegrate[f[s, T, mN], {s, Max[1.01 mN^2,6.7], Infinity}, 
  Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

The accuracy is terrible:

```
mNTest = 1;
Ttest = 40;
tab = SortBy[Table[{int[mNTest, Ttest]}, {i, 1, 20, 1}], #[[1]] &];
Print["Minimal value:"]
tab[[1]][[1]]
Print["Maximal value:"]
tab[[Length[tab]]][[1]]
```

> 1.75882*10^12
>
> 9.62261*10^12

How to improve the accuracy of the given integral (error < say 5-10%) without a significant slowdown of the integral?

Comment: What if you drop `Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"` and use the default Method instead, is that not fast enough or not accurate enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use the default `Method` and you will be fine.

**Long answer:** Define integration with standard method:

```
f[s_,T_,mN_]:=T/(8*Pi^4)1/(mN^3 (s-1.` mN^2)) (1-mN^2/s)^2 Sqrt[s-6.6564000000000005`]((-0.5` s-1.6641000000000001`) mN^4+(6.863591314910416` -0.5` s) s mN^2+s^2 (1.` s-5.199491314910417`)) BesselK[1,Sqrt[s]/T];
int1[mN_,T_]:=NIntegrate[f[s,T,mN],{s,Max[1.01* mN^2,6.7],Infinity}];
```

For comparison, define a slow version with high working precision:

```
toExact[n_]:=Round[10^16*n]/10^16;
fExact[s_,T_,mN_]:=T/(8*Pi^4)1/(mN^3 (s-mN^2)) (1-mN^2/s)^2 Sqrt[s-toExact[6.6564000000000005`]]((-1/2*s-toExact[1.6641000000000001`]) mN^4+(toExact[6.863591314910416`] -1/2*s) s mN^2+s^2 (s-toExact[5.199491314910417`])) BesselK[1,Sqrt[s]/T];
int2[mN_,T_]:=NIntegrate[fExact[s,T,mN],{s,Max[toExact[1.01]* mN^2,toExact[6.7]],Infinity},WorkingPrecision->100]//N;
```

Compare

```
result1 = int1[1,40]
result2 = int2[1,40]
(result1-result2)/result1 (* relative error *)
```

The result is

```
6.45711*10^12
6.45711*10^12
1.67995*10^-12
```

So at least for these parameter values, the relative error is extremely small, suggesting that `int1` is both fast and accurate.

Comment: Honestly, I don't even see the point of using Monte Carlo for a one-dimensional integral...